# Exception caught by gesture. Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, null, provider

[here is the error message from the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZfXs.jpg)

user.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class User {
  final String email;
  final String uid;
  final String photoUrl;
  final String username;
  final String bio;
  final List<String> followers;
  final List<String> following;

  const User({
    required this.email,
    required this.uid,
    required this.photoUrl,
    required this.username,
    required this.bio,
    required this.followers,
    required this.following,
  });

  static User fromSnap(DocumentSnapshot snap) {
    var snapshot = snap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return User(
      username: snapshot["username"],
      uid: snapshot["uid"],
      email: snapshot["email"],
      photoUrl: snapshot["photoUrl"],
      bio: snapshot["bio"],
      followers: snapshot["followers"],
      following: snapshot["following"],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "username": username,
        "uid": uid,
        "email": email,
        "photoUrl": photoUrl,
        "bio": bio,
        "followers": followers,
        "following": following,
      };
}
```

user_provider

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:social_network/models/user.dart';
import 'package:social_network/resources/auth_method.dart';

class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  User? _user;
  final AuthMethods _authMethods = AuthMethods();

  User get getUser => _user!;

  Future<void> refreshUser() async {
    User? user = await _authMethods.getUserDetails();
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

add_post_screen

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:social_network/providers/user_provider.dart';
import 'package:social_network/resources/firestore_methods.dart';
import 'package:social_network/utils/colors.dart';
import 'package:social_network/utils/utils.dart';

class AddPostScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddPostScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AddPostScreenState createState() => _AddPostScreenState();
}

class _AddPostScreenState extends State<AddPostScreen> {
  Uint8List? _file;
  bool _isLoading = false;
  final TextEditingController _descriptionController = TextEditingController();

  _selectImage(BuildContext parentContext) async {
    return showDialog(
        context: parentContext,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return SimpleDialog(
            title: const Text('Create a post'),
            children: <Widget>[
              SimpleDialogOption(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: const Text('Take a photo'),
                onPressed: () async {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  Uint8List file = await pickImage(ImageSource.camera);
                  setState(() {
                    _file = file;
                  });
                },
              ),
              SimpleDialogOption(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: const Text('Choose from gallery'),
                onPressed: () async {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  Uint8List file = await pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);
                  setState(() {
                    _file = file;
                  });
                },
              ),
              SimpleDialogOption(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: const Text('Cancel'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  void postImage(
    String uid,
    String username,
    String profileImage,
  ) async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    try {
      String res = await FirestoreMethods().uploadPost(
          _descriptionController.text, _file!, uid, username, profileImage);
      if (res == "Succes") {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
        showSnackBar('Posted!', context);
        clearImage();
      } else {
        showSnackBar(res, context);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      showSnackBar(e.toString(), context);
    }
  }

  void clearImage() {
    setState(() {
      _file = null;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _descriptionController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final UserProvider userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);
    return _file == null
        ? Center(
            child: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.upload),
              onPressed: () => _selectImage(context),
            ),
          )
        : Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
              leading: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                onPressed: clearImage,
              ),
              title: const Text('Post to'),
              centerTitle: false,
              actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => postImage(
                    userProvider.getUser.uid,
                    userProvider.getUser.username,
                    userProvider.getUser.photoUrl,
                  ),
                  child: const Text(
                    'Post',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            body: Column(
              children: [
                _isLoading
                    ? const LinearProgressIndicator()
                    : const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                      ),
                const Divider(),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522441815192-d9f04eb0615c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=654&q=80',

    //   userProvider.getUser.photoUrl,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: _descriptionController,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Write a caption...',
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                        ),
                        maxLines: 8,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 45,
                      width: 45,
                      child: AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: 487 / 451,
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: MemoryImage(_file!),
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Divider(),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ));
  }
}
```

auth_methods.dart

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:social_network/models/user.dart' as model;
import 'package:social_network/resources/storage_methods.dart';

class AuthMethods {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future<model.User?> getUserDetails() async {
    User currentUser = _auth.currentUser!;

    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
        await _firestore.collection('user').doc(currentUser.uid).get();

    return model.User.fromSnap(documentSnapshot);
  }

  //sign up the user
  Future<String> signUpUser({
    required String email,
    required String password,
    required String username,
    required String bio,
    required Uint8List? file,
  }) async {
    String res = "Some error occurred";
    try {
      if (email.isNotEmpty ||
          password.isNotEmpty ||
          username.isNotEmpty ||
          bio.isNotEmpty ||
          file != null) {
        //register the user
        UserCredential cred = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password);

        String photoUrl = await StorageMethods()
            .uploadImageToStorage('profilePictures', file!, false);

        //adding user to our database

        model.User _user = model.User(
          bio: bio,
          username: username,
          uid: cred.user!.uid,
          email: email,
          photoUrl: photoUrl,
          following: [],
          followers: [],
        );

        await _firestore.collection("users").doc(cred.user!.uid).set(
              _user.toJson(),
            );
        res = "Succes";
      } else {
        res = "Please enter all the fields";
      }
    } catch (err) {
      res = err.toString();
    }
    return res;
  }

// logging the user
  Future<String> loginUser(
      {required String email, required String password}) async {
    String res = "Some error occured";
    try {
      if (email.isNotEmpty || password.isNotEmpty) {
        await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password);
        res = "Succes";
      } else {
        res = "Please enter all the fields required";
      }
    } catch (err) {
      res = err.toString();
    }
    return res;
  }
}
```

Hello. I'll try to make a post button and when I try to upload a photo and press the post button I receive this error.

Do you have any solution for this error? Thanks a lot!

Error message:

Restarted application in 474ms.
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
Null check operator used on a null value
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
[VERBOSE-2:profiler_metrics_ios.mm(203)] Error retrieving thread information: (os/kern) object terminated

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue in

```
onPressed: () => postImage(
                userProvider.getUser.uid,
                userProvider.getUser.username,
                userProvider.getUser.photoUrl,
              ),
```

Make sure that the user is not null before calling the method,
It would be more helpful to post more code `_authMethods.getUserDetails();` what’s inside this method?

---

**UPDATE:**

```
Future<model.User?> getUserDetails() async {
    User currentUser = _auth.currentUser!;

    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
    await _firestore.collection('user').doc(currentUser.uid).get();

    //add the following lines
    print('documentSnapshot: $documentSnapshot');
    if(documentSnapshot == null) return null;

    return model.User.fromSnap(documentSnapshot);
}
```

Comment: Hello, Abdallah. I updated the question with the code from auth_methods.dart

Comment: Hi, Abdallah. Do you know any solution?

Comment: I updated my answer, plus, can you include the implementation of your `User` class

Comment: I updated the answer with the 'User' class. Also, I added these lines from the answer and I received this error:

Error: A value of type 'User?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'User' because 'User?' is nullable and 'User' isn't.
package:social_network/providers/user_provider.dart:12
- 'User' is from 'package:social_network/models/user.dart' ('lib/models/user.dart').
package:social_network/models/user.dart:1
    User user = await _authMethods.getUserDetails();

Comment: Yes, you should write `User? user = await _authMethods.getUserDetails();` instead of `User user = await _authMethods.getUserDetails();`.  did you add the `print` method inside your `getUserDetails` method? if yes, please provide me with the result

Comment: Yes, I added the `print` method in `auth_method.dart` and when I restarted the app, I receive these 2 errors that send me to user.provider (And says the problem is at _user!) and the second one, send me to add_postscreen (and say the problem is userProvider.getUser.uid)

Comment: That’s because ‘ _auth.currentUser!’ is null but you added the not-null expression

Comment: Ok. But if I'll delete `!` I'll receive an error in `onPressed: () => postImage(
                userProvider.getUser.uid,
                userProvider.getUser.username,
                userProvider.getUser.photoUrl,
              ),`

Comment: That should be handled because if the user is null then you can’t update his image, onPressed: (){ if(userProvider.getUser == null) return; postImage(                 userProvider.getUser!.uid,                 userProvider.getUser!.username,                 userProvider.getUser!.photoUrl,               );